# Show a list of pages but hide the current page from the list

Tags: craft3, globals, request

#### My setup

I'd like to show a navigation menu listing all my page entries.
In my layout file, I include a template for the navigation:

_layout.twig:

```
    <main>
      <section id="nav">
        {% include "_includes/navigation.twig" %}
      </section>

      <section id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
      </section>
    </main>
```

The current page is shown in the content block.

#### My question

Is there a way to globally access the currently viewed page, from inside the navigation.twig template. That way I could do:

```
{% set currentPageId = SOME_COOL_GLOBAL_FUNCTION %}
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').id('not ' ~ currentPageId).all() %}
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        {% for page in pages %}
            <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the entries in the section with the handle `pages` have their own URLs. This means that if you visit a URL that belongs to an entry in that section Craft will automatically make that entry available in the template as the `entry` variable. That being said your solution is in this case:

```
{% set currentPageId = entry.id %}
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').id('not ' ~ currentPageId).all() %}
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        {% for page in pages %}
            <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Or as an alternative:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').all() %}
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        {% for page in pages if page.id != entry.id %}
            <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is a read about how Twig handles variable scope if you ask yourself why the `entry` variable is available in the included template:
https://nystudio107.com/blog/twig-processing-order-and-scope

Also, here is a link to Twig's docs on conditional for loops: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, and the explanation link too!